# How to create unit test for class constructor in xUnit?

Tags: c#, xunit

Say I have this class:

```
public class BankAccount : IBankAccount
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int BankAccountNo { get; private set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; private set; }

    public BankAccount(int BankAccountNo, decimal Balance)
    {
        this.BankAccountNo = BankAccountNo;

        if(Balance <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Create bank account failed. Balance should be more than zero.");
        }

        this.Balance = Balance;
    }

    public void Deposit(BankTransaction bankTransaction)
    {
        if (bankTransaction.TransactionAmount <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Deposit failed. Transaction amount is more than account balance.");
        }

        this.Balance += bankTransaction.TransactionAmount;

        // Insert transaction record at BankTransaction Repository class
    }
}
```

My previous design is Deposit have `BankAccount` in the method parameter. With this design, I could create unit test for `Deposit` method as below:

```
    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(DepositShouldPass_Data))]
    public void DepositShouldPass(BankAccount account, BankTransaction bankTransaction, BankAccount accountExpected)
    {
        // Act
        _bankAccount.Deposit(account, bankTransaction);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(accountExpected.Balance, _bankAccount.Balance);
    }

    public static TheoryData<BankAccount, BankTransaction, BankAccount> DepositShouldPass_Data()
    {
        return new TheoryData<BankAccount, BankTransaction, BankAccount>
        {
            {
                new BankAccount(123, 250.00M),
                new BankTransaction(50.00M),
                new BankAccount(123, 300.00M)
            },
            {
                new BankAccount(321, 150.50M),
                new BankTransaction(10.50M),
                new BankAccount(321, 160.00M)
            }
        };
    }
```

But now, I want to re-design `BankAccount` class by removing `BankAccount` as method parameter in `Deposit` method. With this new design, how do I pass test data using xUnit? Secondly is how do I create unit test for my constructor?

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited to elaborate my issue.

Comment: The confusion is *I want to re-design BankAccount class by removing BankAccount as method parameter in Deposit method.* `Deposit` method is member of `BankAccount`. Are you referring to the test? (ie `DepositShouldPass`)

Comment: Yes, the unit test is based on `BankAccount` class. I mean the old design is `public void Deposit(BankAccount account, BankTransaction bankTransaction)` which I could create the unit test as posted. But, now my new design is `public void Deposit(BankTransaction bankTransaction)` which I am not sure how to get the unit test to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```cs
var bankAccountNo = new Random().Next();
var balance = 0;
BankAccount TestCode() => new BankAccount(bankAccountNo, balance);
var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(TestCode);
Assert.StartsWith("Create bank account failed. Balance should be more than zero.", exception.Message);
```

And this:

```cs
var bankAccountNo = new Random().Next();
var balance = new Random().Next();
var bankAccount = new BankAccount(bankAccountNo, balance);
Assert.Equal(bankAccountNo, bankAccount.BankAccountNo);
Assert.Equal(balance, bankAccount.Balance);
```